# WCF Web API Host Project Type

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, wcf-web-api

I am used to creating traditional WCF services and hosting them in IIS. I do this by creating a WCF Service Application within Visual Studio.

For my next project I want to leverage the functionality found in the new [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/). However I am not sure what type of project I need to create to host the service.

Nearly all the examples I have read/seen show the service hosted in a ASP.NET Empty Web Application. Is this correct? Can I not host in in a WCF Application project and add the Web API references in that from NuGet?

I did try hosting in a WCF Application but soon fell over when it came to routing and the MapServiceRoute call in the Global.asax file which gets called on Application_Start.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I gathered from the samples, you can create the WCF as you have been creating, that is, a **WCF Service Application** in the WEB folder of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, do you have any links to samples that show this? I did try this but was unsuccessful as could not get the routing to work correctly

Comment: I guess you can simply download and see the sample from the source code on the site.

Comment: Got it working from the codeplex demo source. It seems they do use a web project but i created a WCF Application project and used the same code in the demo's Global.asax and it worked like a charm!